# Do not render html formatting whitespace in the webpage

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I have the following code to generate some spans using cakephp's helper

```
<div id="numberRow">
    <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('class' => 'numbers', 'separator' => '', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'first' => 1, 'last' => 1)); ?>
</div>
```

This generates the following code:

```
<div id="numberRow">
    <span class="current">1</span><span><a href="/posts/show/barter/page:2" class="numbers">2</a></span>
</div>
```

The problem is that the browser renders a space after the `<span>` which I do not want.

My solution so far is to write the cake as follows:

```
<div id="numberRow">
            <span class="current">1</span><span><a href="/posts/show/barter/page:2" class="numbers">2</a></span></div>
```

with the closing tag on the same row as the `<span>` but that breaks up the format and makes the source harder to read.

Is there a better way?

Comment: *makes the source harder to read.* Do not spend too much time worrying about this. Spend it on making the markup, style and code work. :)

Comment: Could we get the code for this function: `$this->Paginator->number`?

Comment: @Levi - I would imagine that is a CakePHP helper. Maybe this one: http://api13.cakephp.org/file/cake/libs/view/helpers/paginator.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news! There is a CSS style which is aimed at solving this exact problem. It's called `white-space-collapse`, and it looks like this in your stylesheet:

```
#numberRow {white-space-collapse: discard;}
```

In browsers which support it, this will cause white space between tags within the `<div>` to be dropped if there aren't any other characters around them.

Now for the bad news... there isn't a single browser which supports it yet.  :(

The faster moving browsers will probably support it very soon -- I'd be willing to bet it'll be in Chrome at least by the end of the year -- but that's not going to be enough support to make it worth using for some time to come.

In the meanwhile, this is a common problem which plagues a lot of site designers.

The most common solution is simply to remove the white spaces from your source code, as per the example you gave in the question. Its not ideal, but it does solve the problem, and without any messy hacks.

If you're determined to keep your source code tidy (or you simply can't avoid it due to a framework you're using, or whatever), there are a few more hacky solutions:

First is to use a Javascript string replacement when the page loads to trim out the unwanted spaces. This is messy, but does work, except in the rare occasion when the user has disabled javascript. You may get some page refresh problems as it loads first with the one layout and then immediately resyncs itself to the correct layout, but it'll probably be minimal (depending on the browser speed and the scale of the problem).

An even messier solution, but undoubtedly a clever hack, is to set `font-size:0;` for the parent element (in your case, the `<div>`), and then set `font-size` back to the correct size for the content elements. eg:

```
#numberRow {font-size:0;}
#numberRow>span {font-size:12px;}
```

(replacing '12px' with whatever size you happen to want them to be, of course)

The disadvantages of this are: Firstly, it's a horrible hack; secondly, it's a horrible hack; and thirdly, it can make your font sizing difficult to control if you're using and em-based size layout rather than fixed pixel sized fonts. But it does work.

All in all, my recommendation is to go with the easy answer, and remove the spaces in your PHP code. At least until the proper CSS solution is in place in most people's browsers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good post. IMO it's foolhardy to put a hack in specifically to "prettify" the markup for human eyes, but I've see people jump through hoops for it.

Comment: Nice answer, although it leads to the same conclusion as both my example and the other answer, I like this a lot more as it provides a potential fix to use for the future and some other alternatives (with pros and cons analysis) rather than just restate my own example. I'll simply use the uglier markup for now since it isn't a big deal, but I'll keep in mind white-space-collapse for the future when it becomes more supported. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you just do this?

```
<div id="numberRow"><?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('class' => 'numbers', 'separator' => '', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'first' => 1, 'last' => 1)); ?></div>
```

Comment: Yeah taht works, and is what I am doing currently, I was just curious if it's possible to keep the source formatting. Since this type of problem hasn't occured in other cases before

Comment: @Razor - You could try `white-space` properties on `NumberRow`. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html